# How can I get the FFT of an audio source at a specific time

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I have this code here to connect my source->Analyzer->Speaker

But Im starting the source with `source.start()`  I belive my problem is there,

how can I change it to just analyze source at time = 3 seconds.

```
 source.connect(analyser);
 analyser.connect(audioCtx.destination);

 source.start();
```

// I have this section VVV runing with a push of a button. It responds with the FFT at the time I pressed the button

```
 var bufferLength = analyser.frequencyBinCount;
 var dataArray = new Uint8Array(bufferLength);
 analyser.getByteTimeDomainData(dataArray);

 console.log(analyser);
 console.log(bufferLength);
 console.log(dataArray);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test, but maybe you can pass the offset and duration to [.start()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioBufferSourceNode/start).

```js
source.start(0, 3, 1); //start in 0 seconds, at time 3 seconds, play for 1 second
```

Comment: You can potentially compute the duration necessary for triggering a single time slice of the FFT by using the sample rate of the audio source and the `frequencyBinCount`

Comment: Epic it's working now, I also added timing protocols so I can have repeatable time slices,